# Location of Microsoft .NET Framework Configuration

Tags: ftp, .net-framework, windows-server-2012-r2

I've searched for weeks for the Microsoft .NET Framework X.X Configuration in a Windows Server 2012 (X.X means the version) and found nothing. Some tutorials guide me to Administrative Tools and I found it in Windows 8.1 (cool, it was good for me to test), but I don't find it in the server.

Someone knows where should I find it and, if it should be in administrative tools, why it is not there?

I've seen that Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 are installed in the server, so, it's not about the installation, it's about the configuration.

I need this to be able to send files through FTP from this Windows Server 2012 to another server using an asp.net program I've created and tested in a Windows 8.1 computer

Comment: Is [Mscorcfg.msc (.NET Framework Configuration Tool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc(v=vs.100).aspx) what you are referring to? It is very unlikely that that has anything to do with using FTP; instead you should describe the *actual* problem.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I am looking for, and what solved my trouble when sending files through SftpClient.

Precise picture:

[image]

Without this, the error is

> "Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed".

And that's why I need to do the same in the server, using Mscorcfg.msc (.NET Framework Configuration Tool)

Comment: Image doesn't work.  It's not clear if this is an actual answer or an attempt to comment on own question but you mistakenly created a new account

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: It's an attempt to comment, and I've created the first one as guest; I only have 1 account. And the image works